# Book where the US creates Android children to protect itself from invasion

Tags: story-identification, books, androids

I read a story quite some time ago where the basic premise was that the United States was tragically low on children, and in order to protect itself from invasion (I'm not sure how that actually came about) they created a breed of android children that appeared to be human.  For all intents and purposes, they were treated as human, raised as human, and as far as the android children knew, they were in fact, 100% human.  It may have been 20 years ago that I read it.

The problem comes when the 'children' start to realize that they are not human.  One child commits 'suicide' because of it. The main protagonist was an android girl going through high school. Unfortunately, I don't recall her name. She eventually begins to question her 'realness'.

Comment: Welcome to SFF! This is a good description for the premise of the story but can you remember any of the plot afterwards? Anything that happens throughout? Does the protagonist know she’s an android? Do the others? When did you read this? Was it new at the time? If you want to add anything or change anything here please [edit] your question to do so!

Comment: If someone posts the correct answer, you can accept by clicking on the checkmakr by the voting buttons as per the [tour].

Comment: @William Shade  1) It is possible that the android children are needed to "grorw"into android "adult" soldiers in the militry and workers to produce weapons for the war.  2) Or maybe the android children are needed to give the illusion that the USA has a vast population and so deter potential invaders.

Answer (score 6):

Hmm... I haven't found any invasions involved, but could you be asking for *[Expiration Day](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/17910147-expiration-day)* by William Campbell Powell?

[image: Front cover of Expiration Day]

> What happens when you turn eighteen and there are no more tomorrows?
> It is the year 2049, and humanity is on the brink of extinction….
>
> Tania Deeley has always been told that she’s a rarity: a human child in a world where most children are sophisticated androids manufactured by Oxted Corporation. When a decline in global fertility ensued, it was the creation of these near-perfect human copies called teknoids that helped to prevent the utter collapse of society.
>
> Though she has always been aware of the existence of teknoids, it is not until her first day at The Lady Maud High School for Girls that Tania realizes that her best friend, Siân, may be one. Returning home from the summer holiday, she is shocked by how much Siân has changed. Is it possible that these changes were engineered by Oxted? And if Siân could be a teknoid, how many others in Tania’s life are not real?
>
> Driven by the need to understand what sets teknoids apart from their human counterparts, Tania begins to seek answers. But time is running out. For everyone knows that on their eighteenth “birthdays,” teknoids must be returned to Oxted—never to be heard from again.

Found with a search for `novel "android children" invasion`